# How to layer images one on top of another and make them infinite scroll using css?

Tags: html, image, css, scroll

Im trying to layer 2 images 1 on top of the other and make them scroll infinitely using css. I am able to make the images scroll but not layer them one on top of the other and scroll at different speeds to create an effect.

My css:

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}

#animate-area   { 
    width: 100vw; 
    height: 100vw; 
    background-image: url(http://oi64.tinypic.com/2r7ri29.jpg);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

    animation: animatedBackground 135s linear infinite;
}

#animate-area2  { 
    width: 100vw; 
    height: 100vw; 
    background-image: url(http://oi67.tinypic.com/2niy905.jpg);

    background-repeat: repeat-x;
  position: relative;
    animation: animatedBackground 80s linear infinite;
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<div id="animate-area"></div>
<div id="animate-area2"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnxnjzaq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding `style="position:absolute;z-index:0;"` to the first div and `position:absolute;z-index:1;` to the second div which then layered them on top of each other

Answer (score 0):

change position relative to position absolute.
and also use z-index 1 and 2 for theme. :)

```
 #animate-area   { 
        width: 100vw; 
        height: 100vw; 
        background-image: url(http://oi64.tinypic.com/2r7ri29.jpg);
        background-position: 0px 0px;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1;

        animation: animatedBackground 135s linear infinite;
    }

    #animate-area2  { 
        width: 100vw; 
        height: 100vw; 
        background-image: url(http://oi67.tinypic.com/2niy905.jpg);

        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:2;
        animation: animatedBackground 80s linear infinite;
    }
```